# How to restore blog optimisation functionalities in wordpress version 4.8.1?

Tags: wordpress

How to restore blog optimisation functionalities in wordpress version 4.8.1?

The yoast has been updated several times but blog redability and SEO optimisation options are not appearing properly.

Comment: Please post some code or what you have tried

Comment: Yoast SEO plugin is being used in both local and dev server. But facing problem in the dev server whereas in local it is working fine.